# Is there a payment provider to send money to others via Iban

Tags: sdk, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I've worked with a lot of payment providers already. In a new Application I'm now facing a new usecase. I need to have the possibility to send money to a given IBan and monitor whether the money arrived at the destination or not. Best would be if i can use at least Credit Card or paypal for that.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend using Stripe, it's really easy to set up. You can move money between several IBANs, but the users involved will need to have a Connect account.

**GET transfer status :**

You can check the status of your transfer through the `Payouts` object, through the `status` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try. Can you imaging another way without stripe maybe without any requirement for the receipient to have an account someware just iban ?